# Ads popping everywhere on Android 10

Tags: applications, ads, popup

I have a simple Oppo A15 running Android 10 ColorOS 7.2.

It worked fine for many years but a week ago I started having some issues with ads popping everywhere. When using Chrome or any other app; as I am writing this message it happened twice. The ad is basically as if it's a new app that opens. The content of ads is not really relevant I think.

Any suggestions? It's becoming more and more annoying

Answer (score 0):

I personally use DNS66, an app you can download through F-Droid.

Comment: Answers should be self contained, with a link for reference.  Please edit it to explain what this is, what it does and where you get it from.

Comment: Hi. Could you  explain how DNS66 app would solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I would install a Virus Scanner.  My choice is [Kaspersky](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kms.free).  The basic version is free, but you have to manually press the button to update the virus database.

I am not associated with it in any way.